# 100 shoelaces, pick 2 random ends and tie them together, what is the probability that a loop is created?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The question is:

> There are 100 shoelaces in a box. You pick two random ends and tie them together. Either this results in a longer shoelace (if the two ends
>   came from different pieces), or it results in a loop (if the two ends came from
>   the same piece). What is the probability that this results in a loop?

I was thinking that you first choose one of the random ends which is a $\frac{1}{200}$ probability. Then you choose another end which is a $\frac{1}{199}$ probability. Since the order of choosing the ends don't matter, you've over counted by $2$. Thus we have:

$$P(loop) = \frac{1}{200}\frac{1}{199}2$$

However, according to the solution, the answer is just $\frac{1}{199}$, have I over counted by $100$ somehow? Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it your aim to find the probability that a **specific** shoelace will chosen (ending up as a loop)? That is not asked in the question you mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After picking the first end there are $199$ ends left to be picked as second.

They have equal probability to be picked as second.

Exactly one of them will result in a loop.

So this event has probability $\frac1{199}$.

---

edit concerning your reasoning:

If the end of some shoelace is labeled then there is a probability of $\frac1{200}$ that this end is chosen as first and the probability that the other end is chosen as second is $\frac1{199}$. As you say the order does not matter, so we arrive at probability $2\times\frac1{200}\frac1{199}$ on a loop of the shoelace having the labeled end. That stands for the probability that a **specific** shoelace will be chosen (ending up in a loop). Here there are $100$ equiprobable candidates though.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot that also, the choosing of a particular shoelace doesn't matter, so you need to also multiply by $100$.

You calculated the probability that a loop is created with *one particular* shoelace, and there are $100$ of them and you don't care which one forms the loop.